# React UseEffect not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using a useEffect to fetch information from my backend api. I am using Redux and I dispatch action on useeffect. At first, It works but after page reloads all information become null and i get this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mainImage' of null.
In redux dev tools, it doesnot even call the action and my redux store state it is null. What could be possible error? My other components are working fine , even after reloading page and I am using same method in other components also. I have even checked if my response data are loading or not. I even console.log('HI') in useeffect and it doesnot show

Here is my that component

```
const ProductDetailScreen = ({match,history}) => {
    
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {loading,product,error}= useSelector(state=> state.singleProduct)
    
    
   useEffect(()=>{
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id))
   },[dispatch,match])

   
        
    return (
            
        <div className='my-5 p-3'>
             <Button variant="outline-dark" onClick={()=> history.push('/')}>
         <i className="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Go Back
        </Button> 
        
        {loading ? <Loader/> : error? <AlertMessage>{error}</AlertMessage>:
        (
            <>
            <Row className='my-4'>
            <Col md={4}>
                <Image style={{width:'90%',height:'auto'}} alt='' fluid src={product.mainImage}/>
            </Col>

            <Col md={4}>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Rating value={product.ratings} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}/>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    Quantity: {product.quantity}
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    Buyers: {product.sale}
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <h5>Choose Version :</h5>
                   <ListGroup horizontal>
                   <Row>
                       {product.version.map(pro=>(
                            <Col key={pro._id} className='my-2 d-flex align-items-stretch' md={6}>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                             <Form.Check defaultChecked type="radio" inline name="group1"  aria-label="radio 1" />
                             <h6>Version: {pro.version}</h6>
                             <h6>Price: ${pro.price}  </h6>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            </Col>
                       ))}
                      </Row>
                   </ListGroup>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                 </ListGroup>
                  </Col>
                  </Row>
                  </>
export default ProductDetailScreen
```

My reducer

```
export const getProductFromID = (state={product:null},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        default:
        return state

        case GET_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true}
        case GET_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, product:action.payload}
        case GET_PRODUCT_FAIL:
            return {loading:false,error:action.payload}
    }
}
```

My store

```
const rootReducer= combineReducers({
    productsReducer: getProductsReducer,
    topProducts: getTopProductReducer,
    categories: getCategoriesReducer,
    productCategories : getProductFromCategories,
    singleProduct: getProductFromID
})

const initialState ={};

const middleWare = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare)))

export default store
```

My action creator

```
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRODUCT_REQUEST
        })

        const res = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
        })
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong in my backend api , It works correctly in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload your page, your redux state is reset and hence during the first render, your product value is null and you are trying to access `mainImage` from product which breaks the flow of the page.

To solve this, set the initial state in your reducer to have loading as true

```
export const getProductFromID = (state={product:null, loading: true},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        default:
        return state

        case GET_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true}
        case GET_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, product:action.payload}
        case GET_PRODUCT_FAIL:
            return {loading:false,error:action.payload}
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you but I haven't put initial state loading to false in other components and It works fine

Comment: It depends on how the data is being used, in this specific component, if loading is false, the loader is skipped and you go on to try to access mainPage value from product which isn't yet available. Once you add the loading state, the variable is no longer accessed on initial load and useEffect then makes an API call to fetch the data causing things to work as expected